# SQL group by "date" question

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by, truncate

I'm trying to make a report but I'm having problems with  my archi nemesis  SQL.

I have a table where the close date of a transaction is stored.

I want to know how many transaction per month there was so I did:

```
SELECT trunct( closedate, 'MONTH' ) FROM  MY_TRANSACTIONS
```

I'm using oracle.

I'm getting a list like this:

```
2002-09-01 00:00:00.0
2002-09-01 00:00:00.0
...
2002-10-01 00:00:00.0
2002-10-01 00:00:00.0
...
2002-11-01 00:00:00.0
2002-11-01 00:00:00.0
```

etc.

So I thought "If I add a COUNT( ) in the select and GROUP BY at the end of the statement that should do" but it doesn't. My guess is because each record is treated as a different value : -S

Any hint please?

Thanks.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for the re-tags. Is this really PL-SQL?

Comment: @Oscar: Using TRUNC() in this way is specific to Oracle.  But the issue you're seeing with GROUP BY is vendor-independent; this is how any SQL-compliant implementation works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to group by all non-agg fields.  And you don't want to truncate the date, you want the month part of the date.

so something like

select to_char(datefield, 'Month'), count(*) from ... group by to_char(datefield, 'Month');

Comment: to_char(datefield, 'Month') should do it

Comment: @Arnshea: It did ( partially ) because I think is sum all decembers from the last years...

Comment: Try to_char(datefield, 'MONTH YYYY')

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was doing ( by intuition ) doing exactly that Eric. :)

Comment: It's better form to do: TRUNC(datefield, 'Mon') to truncate the days, hours, minutes, seconds from the date.

Comment: TRUNC will be slightly more efficient, but then you'll probably want to format the output anyway...